# Linking terms to views instead of taxonomy pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have created a view for movie genres, with contextual filters to generate such pages as /horror, /comedy, etc.

When I tag content or users, I want the links which then appear on these pages to refer to the view. Right now they go to the term page.

I have heard that the TVI module is the way to go, but I can't find any documentation about it.

I don't even want these term pages to exist at all - I have essentially made my own, to my own specs. How can I make this happen?

Comment: isnt in 'admin/structure/views ' there is 'Taxonomy term' why dont you put your fields there in view enable it and see its effects

Comment: I don't quite get you? You mean I should name my views URL the same as the default URL given to taxonomy terms?

Comment: can you send me screen shot what your views of horror and comedy looks?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a limited number of terms (genres), you can do the following:

1. Head to Structure > Taxonomy > List Terms (next to your genre category)
2. Click Edit next to a term.
3. Uncheck "Generate automatic URL alias" under the URL Path Settings.
4. Enter the path to your View.
5. Repeat.

You can also use the [PathAuto module](http://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to set up rules for automatic forwarding of Taxonomy links to your Views. Install PathAuto, enable, click Configure, select the Patterns tab, and rewrite the URL path for Taxonomy.

Comment: What do you mean, limited number. They aren't user tags, but another taxonomy I am using could have one thousand or so potential terms. Also, my view is dynamic, do I enter that in the path settings?

Comment: If you're talking about hundreds of terms, you want a more dynamic approach. PathAuto will help you (http://drupal.org/project/pathauto). Install that, click configure, and set the Pattern for Taxonomy terms to match the URL pattern you are using for your Views.

Comment: Will there not be a conflict?

Comment: Should not create a conflict. PathAuto creates URL aliases to your view, even when content (the default Taxonomy page) exists at that path already.

Comment: I tried this, and it replaces the view with the term page.

Comment: URL aliases are already established for existing taxonomy terms. Add a new term/view and see what happens. If that works, you need to update the URLs on existing terms, but you're set up for the future.

Comment: My views are contextual. So, the views pages are genres/%1

So, I created a new taxonomy term, romcom, and it generated a URL genres/romcom. When I navigate to this URL, my view is not appearing, but the message "There is currently no content classified with this term."

One thing I should have mentioned - it's users I'm tagging.

Comment: I'm tearing my hair out over this! I think I might give up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the [path auto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto)module and configuring the taxonomy terms patterns to whatever path you wish.